# Use value from previous config file in interpolation

Tags: python, configuration-files, string-interpolation

I am using a program which uses python's `configparser.ConfigParser` to work with config files as instructions to build a thing. It is set up so that multiple command line file arguments can be specified, and specifications in later files override things set in earlier files.

This means I can set up a basic model in a `trivial.ini` file

```
[admin]
basename = trivial_model
[model basic]
data = data.tsv
```

and extend it with a more complex model `extension.ini`

```
[admin]
basename = trivial_model_extended
[model basic]
model = bsvs
```

and `program trivial.ini extension.ini` will behave as if it had got

```
[admin]
basename = trivial_model_extended
[model basic]
data = data.tsv
model = bsvs
```

Now it would be nice to write this somewhat more modular, to be able to combine multiple such extensions without caring about details too much, giving each a different base file name. I thought maybe this might work

```
[admin]
basename = %(basename)s_extended
[model basic]
model = bsvs
```

but with the current implementation, I get `configparser.InterpolationDepthError: Recursion limit exceeded in value substitution: option 'basename' in section 'admin' contains an interpolation key which cannot be substituted in 10 steps. Raw value: '%(basename)s_extended'`.

**Is there an easy, builtin, or elegant way to enable incremental specifications like this**, either through changing the current implementation (which seems to boil down to

```
parser.add_argument(
    "config",
    nargs="+")

args = parser.parse_args()
c = configparser.ConfigParser()
for conf in args.config:
    c.read(conf)
```

) or through some clever `[default]` sections or values in the config files (or both if necessary)?

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- You cannot recurse the `basename` definition like you did above. My approach is to have a `[DEFAULT]` section with something other than `basename`, for example, the trivial.ini might look like this:

  ```
  [DEFAULT]
  basename_default = default from trivial.ini

  [admin]
  basename = trivial_model

  [model basic]
  data = data.tsv
  ```
- Note that the `[DEFAULT]` section needs to be all uppercase
- Next, I might have an additiona .ini file, which I call more.ini and it looks like this:

  ```
  [admin]
  basename = %(basename_default)s and more
  ```
- Also, you don't need a loop to read the config files: just give the `read()` method a list of filenames where the later file will overwrite the first.

Putting it together:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("config", nargs="+")
args = parser.parse_args('trivial.ini extension.ini more.ini'.split())

cfg = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read(args.config)

admin = 'admin'
model_basic = 'model basic'

print('basename:', cfg.get(admin, 'basename'))
print('defaults:', cfg.defaults())
```

The output:

```
basename: default from trivial.ini and more
defaults: OrderedDict([('basename_default', 'default from trivial.ini')])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Evaluation at `get`-time

Recursive interpolation in the way you are looking for is not possible out-of-the-box because interpolation only acts at the time when `ConfigParser.get(section, option)` is called, not at the time the configuration file is read. From `BasicInterpolation`'s docstring:

```
[...]  All reference expansions are done late, on demand. [...]
```

### How do we fix this?

The `_read` method of `ConfigParser` does calls `self._interpolation.before_read`, but by that time it has already overwritten the old internal values of the `ConfigParser` object, so even

```
class BasicReadInterpolation (configparser.BasicInterpolation):
    def before_read(self, parser, section, option, value):
        L = []
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        interpolations = parser[parser.default_section]
        interpolations.update(parser[section])
        self._interpolate_some(
            parser, option, L, value, section, interpolations, 1)
        return ''.join(L)
```

**will not do the trick all by itself**.

You will also have to overload `ConfigParser._read`, the method which contains most of the parsing magic, and `ConfigParser._join_multiline_values`, which *currently* contains the call to `self._interpolation.before_read`. (Which to me is a silly place to put it.)